# Unable to silently renew OKTA access and ID token using React SPA

Tags: okta

I am using a React SPA application and trying to silently renew OKTA access and ID tokens by calling the /authorize endpoint. I am following the link: [OKTA](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/refresh-tokens/main/#renew-access-and-id-tokens-with-spas) and [Authorize](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#authorize) to renew the tokens.

Executing the endpoint on POSTMAN does not refresh the tokens. Following is the POSTMAN URL:
https://{oktadomain}/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?client_id={clientId}&prompt=none&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login/callback&response_type=token&scope=openid

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look to my reply to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659151/seeking-guidance-on-token-refresh-in-okta-react-application-without-redirecting